# Domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{\sin(\sqrt{x})}$

Tags: functions, roots

I have a question regarding the domain of $f(x)$ when equal to the root of the root of sinus. In other words,

$f(x) = \sqrt{\sin (\sqrt{x})}$.

What I do know is that the domain of $\sqrt{\sin}$ must be larger than $0$, which means is between $[0,\pi]$. However that's clearly only half of the problem.

As much as I try to, I can't wrap my head around this. Could anyone help?

Comment: What Is between $[0,\pi]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First condition: $x$ must be nonnegative.

Second condition:$x$ must satisfy
$$\sin\sqrt x \ge 0\iff 2k\pi\le \sqrt x\le \pi+2k\pi=(2k+1)\pi. $$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as you pointed out, I must work with 2 conditions inherent to the exercice. That is to say, I will end the exercice with not one, but 2 answers, or the conditions themselves. If I've done everything right, the second condition must be $4k^2\pi^2 \le x \le (4k^2 + 4k + 1)\pi^2$. And that should be the domain of the question?

Comment: The domain is the union of these intervals when $k$ varies in $\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Work this from inside out.

The domain of $\sqrt x$ is $x\ge0$. The sine has no domain limitation. Then the outer square root needs a non-negative argument, which occurs when the argument of the sine is in range $[0,\pi]$ plus $2k\pi$ (due to periodicity).

Hence

$$\sqrt x\in[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$$

or

$$x\in[(2k\pi)^2,((2k+1)\pi)^2].$$

To avoid duplicates, $k\ge0$.

Comment: That is to say, 2 final conditions for the equation, them being: $x \ge 0$ and $4k^2\pi^2 \le x \le (4k^2 + 4k + 1)\pi^2$. This second equation should be just the last equation you wrote. I'm surprised and a little bit confused, but I guess this also coincides with what Bernard wrote, right?